# Is classifying one dimensional generalized quasicrystals worthwhile strategy to approach RH?

Tags: soft-question, riemann-hypothesis

*Works done*: After fruitlessly poring over books on zeta functions, it seems Freeman Dyson's [*sotto voce* nudge](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~oyounggo/books/dyson.pdf) to classify generalized one-dimensional quasicrystals is a way to go. As he writes:

[image]

*Question*: Will this be a worthwhile strategy to pursue where a big picture akin to Atiyah-Singer index theorem needs to be made for symmetry?

Comment: I don't think you'll find an answer for this here or in [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: Is this a serious question about the relative merits of this qausicrystal approach to RH, or did you get taken in by this joke exercise thinking it was meant for-real? (Either way, I'm **not** downvoting: if the former, a satisfactory answer may very well be possible by some expert; if the latter, I don't see the point of adding downvote to injury.)

Comment: @anon I did not know this was a "joke exercise". Can you provide more details?

Comment: If you would do a simple google search for the Riemann Hypothesis, you would find out that it is one of the most famous open problems in all of mathematics. Hence the humor in asking a reader to prove it as a mere exercise. Your question will in all likelihood be closed unless you want to change the nature of it. | Edit: apparently you [already knew](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96642/current-status-of-the-riemann-hypothesis/96646#96646) this. How could you not tell this was a joke? | Edit 2: Alright, now IMO it is not close-worthy.

Comment: I edited the title.

Comment: i think 'NO' .. even if you foudn a system whith the Riemann zeros, it could be that ther are zeros outside the critical line which do ont appear inisd ethe quasycritstal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proof of the pudding is in the eating -- if following the program leads to a proof of RH, then *ipso facto* it is a worthwhile strategy. If it doesn't lead to the RH but does leads to other interesting things, it can reasonably be said to be worthwhile anyway. If it leads nowhere, then it wasn't worthwhile.

Which of those are the case nobody can say until it's actually been tried.

What kind of answer were you expecting? Anyone who can answer either of

- Yes, this *will* lead to a proof of RH.
- No, there cannot exist any proof of RH that uses these ideas even as an informal source of intuition; it's certain to be useless.

should be out there winning an Abel prize for themselves, not doodling about on MSE.

Comment: *doodle, doodle, doodle...* (+1)