# Which fields of math would I need to study to fully understand/solve the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: prime-numbers

Apart from analytic number theory / complex analysis to actually knowing what it's about, which fields of math should I master to have a chance at solving it?

I understand that the answer may come unexpectedly from anywhere, but I have limited time and would like to at least try delving into this matter.

Comment: I'd rather say "all of them". We still do not know what the key to the RH will be. And if I know, maybe I would not tell you.

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Attempts_to_prove_the_Riemann_hypothesis 
and maybe here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39944/collection-of-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis

Comment: start here: http://modular.math.washington.edu/rh/

Comment: @supinf thanks.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156616/is-classifying-one-dimensional-generalized-quasicrystals-worthwhile-strategy-to/156738#156738)

Comment: I'd rather say "most of them". We only have a vague idea of what the key to the RH will be. And since I love fractals, I'll show you some of the lesser known properties of the Riemann zeta function. [Look here](http://visualizingmath.tumblr.com/post/111816953061/riemann-zeta-function-some-fractal-like-patterns). If you're intrigued a quick search will pull up a plethora of more detailed information.

Comment: The book _Prime Obsession_ by John Derbyshire is a wonderful introduction to the problem.

Comment: Asking what kind of mathematics one needs to _solve_ some unsolved problem is too broad. While there are mainstream approaches to solving RH, using analytic number theory, there are also lots of non-classical approaches (Connes' $\Bbb F_1$ approach, Iwaniec's approach, etc.), and, as far as I know, we have no idea which one is the right one. That being said, I don't think anyone has any idea of how much mathematics is needed to solve RH.